# For loop produces "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops

I am having an issue with a simple for loop setup in my app. Upon reaching the second for loop, my app crashes and I get the error below:

```
for (NSArray *a in dict)
            {
                for (NSString *s in a)
                {

                }
            }
```

Error:

```
-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5b6810
```

This seems slightly strange. I just want to look at each array in my dictionary, then as I get to them in the loop, check the strings in those arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
for (NSArray *a in [dict allValues])
```

since based on your error message, your keys appear to be strings (`__NSCFString`). The behaviour of `for (NSArray *s in dict)` is to enumerate the *keys* of the dictionary.

Comment: To add to this - as the original code is written in the OP, you are iterating over all of the keys in the dictionary. Greg's answer gives you all of the values in dictionary.

Comment: Your update is incorrect. Any object that is copyable can be a key in a dictionary. Your statement about keys needing to be strings is only true if you plan to write the dictionary to a plist file.

Comment: @rmaddy: fascinating, I wouldn't have expected that. Will fix.

Comment: The Overview in the NSDictionary reference docs has a clear statement about this. Fine reading it is :)